# Rigging a robotic arm

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I made a model and an armature, which I did not parented yet to the mesh. I want the robot rotate towards a specific bone. Through IK I can move the whole armature towards this bone but I want the robot only to be able to rotate on the z axis. So when I move this controller bone, the robot armature should rotate towards this position on the z-axis. Is this possible in blender?

Comment: I erased the link form the question because it had expired. In the future please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.
In every IK chain you can select a bone and set some constraints in the IK tab of the bone section of the properties panel. The XYZ constraints are referred to the bone axis, not to the global orientation.

[image]

Comment: I managed to make the armature almost work as intended, but I want to "skip" one bone in the IK chain, namely the topConnector bone, is this possible? So no matter what, this bone should have the same rotation on the x-axis in world space, so not dependant on the parents rotation on this axis.http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38948